# Node-webkit - localStorage is behaving like sessionStorage

Tags: html, local-storage, node-webkit

Working on desktop using node-webkit. LocalStorage of chrome persist even after restarting browser or machine. Chromium of node-webkit does not persist information when node-webkit started again.

Hope I am clear here with question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use the localstorage and i is fully persistent. any chance you switched domains?

Comment: No. Its a desktop app. All are fetched from file system

Comment: can you post any code? package.json and any main.js and index.html you might use might help. as I said, i use the localstorage and never had any issues with that.